# libreoffice problem while install ubuntu-desktop

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, gdm

when I reinstall ubuntu-desktop, I have libreoffice problem:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice-common
 libreoffice-gnome
 libreoffice-impress
 python3-uno
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh
 libreoffice-core
 libreoffice-script-provider-js
 libreoffice
 libreoffice-calc
 libreoffice-base
 libreoffice-math
 libreoffice-gtk3
 libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
 libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
 libreoffice-writer
 libreoffice-report-builder
 libreoffice-draw
 libreoffice-java-common
 libreoffice-base-drivers
 libreoffice-wiki-publisher
 libreoffice-script-provider-python
 libreoffice-nlpsolver
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin
 libreoffice-sdbc-firebird
 libreoffice-sdbc-mysql
 libreoffice-base-core
```

when I do :

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

I have:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice-common
 libreoffice-gnome
 libreoffice-impress
 python3-uno
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh
 libreoffice-core
 libreoffice-script-provider-js
 libreoffice
 libreoffice-calc
 libreoffice-base
 libreoffice-math
 libreoffice-gtk3
 libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
 libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
 libreoffice-writer
 libreoffice-report-builder
 libreoffice-draw
 libreoffice-java-common
 libreoffice-base-drivers
 libreoffice-wiki-publisher
 libreoffice-script-provider-python
 libreoffice-nlpsolver
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin
 libreoffice-sdbc-firebird
 libreoffice-sdbc-mysql
 libreoffice-base-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I suggest you read the actual error message(s), and not the final *summary* report you pasted; scroll up the messages as the message that matters was earlier. Packages are built for specific releases, and we don't know yours unless we're told, and your *tags* make little sense as you've tagged Kubuntu (using KDE Plasma) & gdm (GNOME display manager) used by different *flavors*??